# Angular Directive with templateUrl - Issue on Plunker?

Tags: angularjs, plunker

Can I link to a specific file within a Plunker?  Specifically, I'd like to use Angular's "templateUrl" within a directive to externalize the HTML for a directive I'm building:

```
myApp.directive('groupedlist', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    templateUrl: '/groupedList.html',
    link: function() {}
  };
});
```

I have a file called "groupedList.html" that contains a HTML template, but it seems like these are logical files within a Plunker project - my browser complains because it can't find groupedList.html.  Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do using Plunker?  I'd rather not use the "template" attribute because there is a not-insignificant amount of HTML content I'd like to externalize.

Comment: They're relative paths. Use `templateUrl: 'groupedList.html'` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work.  The browser reports trying and failing to load this url: http://run.plnkr.co/groupedList.html

Comment: It should work.  Can you provide a link to your plunker?

Comment: My mind is kind of blown, but in the process of trying to simplify the Plunker in order to share it, it started working!  I think it was some nuanced thing I was doing wrong with camel casing vs. snake casing as I named and referenced the custom directive.  Sorry, and thank you - it works!

Comment: I have had several instances where the running/preview version of the Plunker has simply not aligned with the current code. Refreshing the app page (not the preview) works. But, glad it's solved!

Answer (score 4):

templateUrl doesnt work with absolute URLs, use relative URL instead (like './page.html' or '../templates/page.html'). If u need to load cross domain page to template, u can do a request (XMLHttpRequest) and set STRING HTML as a template.

Answer (score 0):

Like what Rafael said, but just to add...if you put your files in a subfolder like i did, use: 
`templateUrl: 'app/home.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/home.css'],`

You would think `'./home.html'` would work but it doesn't even though my component is in the same folder.